# How can the 6.5 m primary mirror of the JWST fit inside the 5.4 m fairing of Ariane 5?

Tags: payload, james-webb-telescope, ariane, fairings

All the variants of the payload fairing for Ariane 5 are [5.4 meters](http://www.spacelaunchreport.com/ariane5.html) in diameter, the same as the core stage of the rocket. At the same time, the mirror of the James Webb Space Telescope is [6.5 meters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope#Optics). That looks like a very basic geometric problem to me. Although the mirror is modular, it is supposed to be launched in one piece, and not assembled in orbit.

There is even a diagram of the telescope nicely fitting in the fairing:

[image: JWST in payload fairing]

<sub><sub>By NASA (James Webb Space Telescope in Ariane 5 fairing) [Public domain], via Wikimedia Commons</sub></sub>

The only possibility I can see is that the payload fairing is custom made significantly wider than any earlier fairing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The JWST is made to fold up, to fit inside the standard fairing. You can sort of see this in your image, 3 mirror segments are visible (the hexagons in the middle), other segments are viewed side-on and aren't visible.

[Folding animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30Lv8JjCqhU)

[Time lapse showing the folding during assembly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGaagak_ACE)

Comment: By the time we can get people into space easily, we won't actually need people in space. Robotics and AI will handle everything - except of course to fill the rooms and zero-gee swimming pools of the space-hotels, and of course as a "backup bio population" if Earth is destroyed and the AI still needs us or at least wants to keep us around. The JWST is an amazing thing - self-assemble, self-align, self-operate, self-correct its unstable orbit...    Therefore [this question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/18504/12102).