# Could the Electron launch a cubesat to Mars

Tags: mars, cubesat, electron, capstone

Could the [Electron](https://www.spacelaunchreport.com/electron.html) in combination with it's kickstage deliver any meaningful mass to Mars, ie; a 2kg cubesat or is it unable to reach the required velocities even with no payload. Rocketlab are  offering a [service](https://spacenews.com/rocket-lab-to-offer-lunar-missions-ground-station-services/) of around 20kg to a Lunar orbit and recently got the [award](https://spacenews.com/rocket-lab-wins-contract-to-launch-nasa-lunar-cubesat-mission/) for the CAPSTONE mission, and getting to a Lunar orbit from memory isn't that much more extreme compared to just getting a Mars flyby.

Comment: I just realized that there are [now two](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41869/12102) CAPSTONE questions so I added a new tag [since I suspect that there will be more questions about it](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1478/12102).

Comment: “We actually showed that we could not only get to the moon, but we can do near-interplanetary stuff. We can go to Venus, we can go to Mars,” Beck said. https://www.cnbc.com/2020/04/08/rocket-labs-helicopter-snags-parachute-in-test-key-to-reusing-rockets.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating this answer in light of this [paper](https://baas.aas.org/pub/2021n4i366/release/1?readingCollection=7272e5bb) released by Rocketlab 3 months ago for the Decadal survey. And it has a lot on the deep space capabilities of Electron + Photon, not just Venus and Mars.

[image: Photon Deep space Payloads]

So, yes Electron + Photon can send a payload to Mars; specifically 34kg on a flyby, with the ability to go into a hyperbolic orbit with 10kg of mass. Electron can also send a Photon to Jupiter via a VEEGA route. That's neat. It can also rideshare on a GTO mission to get more performance.

Of course it's worth noting the [recent contract](https://www.rocketlabusa.com/about-us/updates/rocket-lab-awarded-contract-to-design-twin-spacecraft-for-mars/)  Rocketlab got for the spacecraft for the Mars mission ESCAPADE, but those will be launching directly to Mars on a NASA provided CLV; so it won't be Electron launching those missions.

Also check out at the [C3 graph](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIlNIVXpIns). Pretty neat huh.
[image: C3 Graph]