# How many cubesat U's is CAPSTONE really?

Tags: nasa, cubesat, autonomy, capstone

Wikipedia's [CAPSTONE(spacecraft); Spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPSTONE_(spacecraft)#Spacecraft) says:

> The orbiter is a 12-unit CubeSat

but looking at the images in the new NASA video [NASA 2021: Let's Go to the Moon](https://youtu.be/_fRSaLAEW2s) I see artwork that shows Capstone as a square-based prism with the long side about twice the length of the other two, which looks like it's going to have a payload volume much more consistent with 16U than 12U.

Are they still calling it 12U? Does Rocket Lab say anything about their payload volume to the Moon or how large CAPSTONE is?

- [How many times will the Photon fire its Curie in order to "reach the right spot" to deploy CAPSTONE towards the Moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46369/12102)
- [How will NASA's software for autonomous navigation in cis-lunar space be tested; what information is processed, what outputs evaluated?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41869/12102) (unanswered)
- [What is the largest proper cubesat?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45919/12102)
- [Have there been any square 4U (2x2) cubesats?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45685/12102)

---

Screenshots from the linked NASA video (click for full size)

[image: Screenshot from NASA 2021: Let's Go to the Moon] [image: Screenshot from NASA 2021: Let's Go to the Moon]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a 12U "base" with a protruding antenna and related equipment. It's quite a custom spacecraft because it'll be demoing the Cislunar Autonomous Position System (among other things like "how to perform real-world navigation in an NRHO").

For CAPS, it will communicate with the Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter when it passes near its Moon periapse, and hence the custom antenna setup which makes it look like it isn't a 12U.

Comment: Can I simply say "personal knowledge" too? I was the payload specialist and onboard navigation lead on the mission.

Comment: In this particular case it's okay with me